# Processing mulitple similar rows in Pandas

Tags: sql, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe pulled from a relational database. A one-to-many join has resulted in many similar rows with one column different. I would like to combine the similar rows but have the differing column data contained within a list, for each unique row. I am also able to change the SQL but I think this may be easier to do downstream within Pandas.

Here is a reproducable example:

```
    # example of SQL to fetch data from upstream source
    df = pd.read_sql('''
        select
            emp_no,
            concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) as "name",
            title        
        from employees
        join titles using (emp_no)
        limit 10;
    ''', engine)
    
    # or create the DF from a dict() - to enable recreation of exact data stucture
    df = pd.DataFrame({'emp_no': {0: 10001,
  1: 10002,
  2: 10003,
  3: 10004,
  4: 10004,
  5: 10005,
  6: 10005,
  7: 10006,
  8: 10007,
  9: 10007},
 'name': {0: 'Georgi Facello',
  1: 'Bezalel Simmel',
  2: 'Parto Bamford',
  3: 'Chirstian Koblick',
  4: 'Chirstian Koblick',
  5: 'Kyoichi Maliniak',
  6: 'Kyoichi Maliniak',
  7: 'Anneke Preusig',
  8: 'Tzvetan Zielinski',
  9: 'Tzvetan Zielinski'},
 'title': {0: 'Senior Engineer',
  1: 'Staff',
  2: 'Senior Engineer',
  3: 'Engineer',
  4: 'Senior Engineer',
  5: 'Senior Staff',
  6: 'Staff',
  7: 'Senior Engineer',
  8: 'Senior Staff',
  9: 'Staff'}})
```

This outputs:

|  | name | title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | Georgi Facello | Senior Engineer |
| 10002 | Bezalel Simmel | Staff |
| 10003 | Parto Bamford | Senior Engineer |
| 10004 | Chirstian Koblick | Senior Engineer |
| 10004 | Chirstian Koblick | Engineer |
| 10005 | Kyoichi Maliniak | Staff |
| 10005 | Kyoichi Maliniak | Senior Staff |
| 10006 | Anneke Preusig | Senior Engineer |
| 10007 | Tzvetan Zielinski | Staff |
| 10007 | Tzvetan Zielinski | Senior Staff |

I would like to be able to almagamate the similar rows, creating a list with all the different values for a particular record:

|  | name | titles |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | Georgi Facello | `[Senior Engineer]` |
| 10002 | Bezalel Simmel | `[Staff]` |
| 10003 | Parto Bamford | `[Senior Engineer]` |
| 10004 | Chirstian Koblick | `[Engineer, Senior Engineer]` |
| 10005 | Kyoichi Maliniak | `[Senior Staff, Staff]` |
| 10006 | Anneke Preusig | `[Senior Engineer]` |
| 10007 | Tzvetan Zielinski | `[Senior Staff, Staff]` |

What is the best (most readable, easiest to understand and maintain) way to achieve this, either in SQL or in Pandas? (I suspect this will be a lot easier in pandas but I can adjust the SQL to help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dfnew = df.groupby(['emp_no', 'name'])['title'].apply(list).reset_index()
dfnew
```

Output

```
    emp_no  name                title
0   10001   Georgi Facello      [Senior Engineer]
1   10002   Bezalel Simmel      [Staff]
2   10003   Parto Bamford       [Senior Engineer]
3   10004   Chirstian Koblick   [Engineer, Senior Engineer]
4   10005   Kyoichi Maliniak    [Senior Staff, Staff]
5   10006   Anneke Preusig      [Senior Engineer]
6   10007   Tzvetan Zielinski   [Senior Staff, Staff]
```